# Remove all issue checks from tests in SonarQube, except pattern matchers

Tags: sonarqube

I analyze issues in SonarQube for only source code. I have removed all issue checks from my tests. Howeve, now I want to add a pattern matcher rule (IGNORE tag) for tests also. The actual rule is in place. How can I do this? My current setting for exclusion are:

```
Ignore issues on multiple criteria:
    Rule key pattern: *
    File path pattern: test/**/*.*
```

So I should somehow edit the "Rule kye pattern: *" do exclude all rules *except* the pattern matcher rule?

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues

First, exclude all rules for `test/**/*.*` => Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria | `*` | `test/**/*.*`

Then, include this pattern matcher rule for `test/**/*.*` => Restrict Scope of Coding Rules | `pattern_matcher_rule_id` | `test/**/*.*`